# How do i find and count all objects in JSON

Tags: json, api, postman

I need to find out how many items i have with an ID in an rest API request. Id like to count how many items do i have with ID and than i need to asign them a variable. How could this be done in JSON. Iknow that i have 4 objects with an id but that can change as i run more tests on blazemeter. The counted ID's need to have an assigned variable so that i could use the variable in an url to see session ID.

```
{
    "limit": 20,
    "skip": 0,
    "total": 4,
    "hidden": 0,
    "api_version": 4,
    "error": null,
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 9595495,
            "name": "June_14_11:47 AM - GUI Functional Test",
            "isNewTest": true,
            "userId": 1340257,
            "lastRunTime": 1625040498,
            "created": 1623660458,
            "updated": 1625033944,
            "creatorClientId": "gui",
            "overrideExecutions": [
                {
                    "executor": "selenium",
                    "scenario": "default-scenario",
                    "locations": {
                        "harbor-5d25f94f9950ce73cd105f53": 1
                    },
                    "capabilities": {
                        "platformName": "linux",
                        "browserName": "chrome",
                        "browserVersion": "default",
                        "blazemeter_videoEnabled": true
                    }
                }
            ],
            "executions": [
                {
                    "locationsWeighted": true,
                    "executor": "selenium",
                    "hasDataSources": false,
                    "scenario": "First item purchase",
                    "locations": {
                        "harbor-5d25f94f9950ce73cd105f53": 1
                    },
                    "concurrency": 1,
                    "usersNotConfigured": true,
                    "durationIsNotConfigured": true,
                    "capabilities": {
                        "browserName": "chrome",
                        "browserVersion": "default",
                        "blazemeter_videoEnabled": true
                    }
                }
            ],
            "shouldSendReportEmail": true,
            "projectId": 1021507,
            "lastUpdatedById": 1340257,
            "configuration": {
                "type": "functionalGui",
                "dedicatedIpsEnabled": false,
                "canControlRampup": false,
                "targetThreads": 0,
                "enableFailureCriteria": false,
                "enableMockServices": false,
                "enableTestData": false,
                "enableLoadConfiguration": true,
                "scriptType": "taurus",
                "filename": "functionalGui.yaml",
                "testMode": "script",
                "extraSlots": 0,
                "plugins": {
                    "thresholds": {
                        "thresholds": [],
                        "ignoreRampup": false,
                        "fromTaurus": false,
                        "slidingWindow": false
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 9595540,
            "name": "My first http test",
            "isNewTest": true,
            "userId": 1340257,
            "lastRunTime": 1623661211,
            "created": 1623661196,
            "updated": 1623686973,
            "creatorClientId": "BE_CHROME",
            "overrideExecutions": [
                {
                    "concurrency": 20,
                    "executor": "jmeter",
                    "locations": {
                        "us-central1-a": 20
                    },
                    "locationsPercents": {
                        "us-central1-a": 100
                    },
                    "rampUp": "1m",
                    "holdFor": "19m",
                    "steps": 0
                }
            ],
            "executions": [
                {
                    "concurrency": 20,
                    "usersNotConfigured": false,
                    "holdFor": "19m",
                    "durationIsNotConfigured": false,
                    "rampUp": "1m",
                    "steps": 0,
                    "locations": {
                        "us-central1-a": 20
                    },
                    "locationsPercents": {
                        "us-central1-a": 100
                    },
                    "executor": "jmeter",
                    "scenario": "default-scenario-9595540"
                }
            ],
            "shouldSendReportEmail": true,
            "projectId": 1021507,
            "lastUpdatedById": 1340257,
            "configuration": {
                "type": "taurus",
                "canControlRampup": false,
                "targetThreads": 1,
                "executionType": "taurusCloud",
                "enableFailureCriteria": false,
                "enableMockServices": false,
                "enableTestData": false,
                "enableLoadConfiguration": true,
                "scriptType": "jmeter",
                "threads": 0,
                "filename": "My_first_http_test.jmx",
                "testMode": "script",
                "extraSlots": 0,
                "plugins": {
                    "jmeter": {
                        "version": "auto",
                        "consoleArgs": "",
                        "enginesArgs": ""
                    },
                    "thresholds": {
                        "thresholds": [],
                        "ignoreRampup": false,
                        "fromTaurus": false,
                        "slidingWindow": false
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 9595539,
            "name": "My first http test",
            "isNewTest": true,
            "userId": 1340257,
            "lastRunTime": 1623661204,
            "created": 1623661195,
            "updated": 1623661202,
            "creatorClientId": "BE_CHROME",
            "overrideExecutions": [
                {
                    "concurrency": 20,
                    "executor": "jmeter",
                    "locations": {
                        "us-central1-a": 20
                    },
                    "locationsPercents": {
                        "us-central1-a": 100
                    },
                    "rampUp": "1m",
                    "holdFor": "19m",
                    "steps": 0
                }
            ],
            "executions": [
                {
                    "concurrency": 20,
                    "usersNotConfigured": false,
                    "holdFor": "19m",
                    "durationIsNotConfigured": false,
                    "rampUp": "1m",
                    "steps": 0,
                    "locations": {
                        "us-central1-a": 20
                    },
                    "locationsPercents": {
                        "us-central1-a": 100
                    },
                    "executor": "jmeter",
                    "scenario": "default-scenario-9595539"
                }
            ],
            "shouldSendReportEmail": true,
            "projectId": 1021507,
            "lastUpdatedById": 1340257,
            "configuration": {
                "type": "taurus",
                "canControlRampup": false,
                "targetThreads": 0,
                "executionType": "taurusCloud",
                "enableFailureCriteria": false,
                "enableMockServices": false,
                "enableTestData": false,
                "enableLoadConfiguration": true,
                "scriptType": "jmeter",
                "filename": "My_first_http_test.jmx",
                "testMode": "script",
                "extraSlots": 0,
                "plugins": {
                    "jmeter": {
                        "version": "auto",
                        "consoleArgs": "",
                        "enginesArgs": ""
                    },
                    "thresholds": {
                        "thresholds": [],
                        "ignoreRampup": false,
                        "fromTaurus": false,
                        "slidingWindow": false
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 9595355,
            "name": "My first http test",
            "isNewTest": true,
            "userId": 1340257,
            "lastRunTime": 1623656690,
            "created": 1623656683,
            "updated": 1623656688,
            "creatorClientId": "gui",
            "overrideExecutions": [
                {
                    "concurrency": 5,
                    "executor": "taurus",
                    "holdFor": "19m",
                    "locations": {
                        "us-east4-a": 5
                    },
                    "locationsPercents": {
                        "us-east4-a": 100
                    },
                    "rampUp": "1m",
                    "steps": 0
                }
            ],
            "executions": [
                {
                    "concurrency": 5,
                    "usersNotConfigured": false,
                    "holdFor": "19m",
                    "durationIsNotConfigured": false,
                    "rampUp": "1m",
                    "steps": 0,
                    "locations": {
                        "us-east4-a": 5
                    },
                    "locationsWeighted": true,
                    "locationsPercents": {
                        "us-east4-a": 100
                    },
                    "executor": "jmeter",
                    "hasDataSources": false,
                    "scenario": "default-scenario"
                }
            ],
            "shouldSendReportEmail": false,
            "projectId": 1021484,
            "lastUpdatedById": 1340257,
            "configuration": {
                "type": "taurus",
                "canControlRampup": false,
                "targetThreads": 0,
                "executionType": "taurusCloud",
                "enableFailureCriteria": false,
                "enableMockServices": false,
                "enableTestData": false,
                "enableLoadConfiguration": true,
                "scriptType": "taurus",
                "filename": "blazemeter_url_test_script.yaml",
                "testMode": "http",
                "extraSlots": 0,
                "plugins": {
                    "jmeter": {
                        "version": "auto",
                        "consoleArgs": "",
                        "enginesArgs": ""
                    },
                    "thresholds": {
                        "thresholds": [],
                        "ignoreRampup": false,
                        "fromTaurus": false,
                        "slidingWindow": false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "request_id": "60dc3c023ef70"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(pm.response.json().result.filter(a=>a.id).length)
```

this gives all elements in the result array with property id, and then returns length of that

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store all ids than i don't think there is a way to store list in postman, but you can store all ids as a comma separated string and like this:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var arr = ""
for (var i = 0; i<jsonData.result.length; i++){
    arr += jsonData.result[i].id + ','
}
pm.environment.set("ids", arr);
```